# How to include only three-part file version (without fourth revision number) to the AppVersion value in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

I have created setup for Windows desktop WPF/C# application using Inno Setup 6.0 and it works fine. Just a small cosmetic issue - I would like to use a "semantic version". The version number in Windows has four components, `major.minor.build.revision` but I want to present `major.minor.patch`. The fourth component will be used by CI and has no relevance for user. In the current script, I have this:

```
#define AppVersion GetFileVersion("..\app\bin\Release\app.exe")
... which later gets used as:
[Setup]
AppVersion=AppVersion
OutputBaseFilename=app.{#AppVersion}.x64
```

The result is `app.1.0.1.781.x64.exe` created by Inno Setup, so I'm looking for a way to cut off the last version component - `.781`. So far I haven't figured out how to invoke a script function for that purpose. I could add function in `[Code]` section but it will be defined after `[Setup]` section and apparently cannot be called in `[Setup]` section?

Is it possible to modify the values of `AppVersion` and `OutputBaseFilename` in Pascal script, for instance in `InitializeSetup()`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`GetVersionComponents` preprocessor function](https://jrsoftware.org/ispphelp/index.php?topic=getversioncomponents) (`ParseVersion` before Inno Setup 6.1):

```
#define AppVerText() \
   GetVersionComponents('..\app\bin\Release\app.exe', \
       Local[0], Local[1], Local[2], Local[3]), \
   Str(Local[0]) + "." + Str(Local[1]) + "." + Str(Local[2])
```

Then you can use this in your `[Setup]` section:

```
AppVersion={#AppVerText}
```

You can use this for `OutputBaseFilename` too:

```
OutputBaseFilename=app.{#AppVerText}.x64
```

Comment: How about a way to use the 4th component if it's not 0?